# How to Make a Ajax Call from inside an Div That Has Been Called By Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, html, hyperlink

I Have a PHP page that is like this:

Here is the Schematics:
http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/4895/13423274.jpg

In DIV 1 And DIV 2 i made Ajax calls for Content. The Ajax Calls Are made from the main Page.
If i want to make a call From DIV 1 to change DIV 2 it doesnt Work =/
I Tried:

```
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = data;
```

Can Anyone Help Me? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

An id cannot start with a number, so that could lead to problems.

Apart from that it depends on where your javascript is located and how and when you attach it to your event handler.

If the javascript is included in the code that is loaded in DIV 1, there shouldn´t be a problem, but if it already is on the page, you need to attach it to the newly loaded DIV 1 as soon as it´s loaded.

See for example the [jQuery `.live()` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for a detailed explaination of what I mean.

Comment: Sorry i did wrong, it calls Div2 but, i dont want to use Jquery this one. It seems that inside Div1 it cannot access div2, and inside div2 i cannot access div1

Comment: @Loruaasd I was not suggesting that you use jQuery, I just wanted to point to some more information about binding in case my answer wasn´t clear.

Answer (score 0):

So in DIV1's content you have some links that, say, want to load content in to DIV2? What you'd need to do then is add event listeners to the links in DIV1 so that when they're clicked they'll created AJAX calls that load content into DIV2.

I'd recommend using jQuery (http://jquery.com/) and you can do something like this:

```
// getting the content into DIV1
$( '#div1' ).load( '/path/to/backend.php', function()
{
    // the ajax request is complete, so let's add listeners to the a tags in DIV1
    $( '#div1 a' ).click( function()
    {
        // this clears DIV2's content
        $( '#div2' ).empty();

        // and now we load some ajax by getting the href of the a tag and passing that to our backend
        $( '#div2' ).load( '/path/to/backend.php', { page: $( this ).attr( 'href' ) };
    });
});
```

You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/load/